# Find email attachment size

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I have the following code, where I attach a file as an attachment to a email. I also try to find the size of bodypart(attachment in this case) but it returns me -1. Where am I going wrong ?

```
mBP = new MimeBodyPart();
DataSource source = new FileDataSource(fileName);
mBP.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
content.addBodyPart(mBP);
String attachmentSize = mBP.getSize()+"Bytes";
```

Even though the attachment gets correctly sent, it returns size as -1Bytes.

Comment: Long time since posted, but did you find a solution in the end ?

Answer (score -1):

There is no way you get the exact attachment size from getSize() method. It approximates to 60% of actual size as the method ignores any encoded content. The only way is to read the contents as bytes to figure out the size.

Comment: Yes I know that, there are always headers involved, so the size we get is somewhat higher ( not 60% though), read this : https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2269050 , but in this case getSize returns -1. So I think the way I am taking size is wrong, I can't figure out why though.

Comment: JavaMail only returns the size when it's known by the mail server.  Since you're creating the message, the mail server doesn't know anything about it, and the only way JavaMail could figure out the size is to check the file.  You can do that yourself, assuming what you care about is the decoded size of the file, not the encoded size.

Comment: found a value that worked well: 0.725f of received size